# Scaling on iPhone / iPad with percentages

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiimage, scale

This is the way I add buttons and labels with images to my views.

Currently I have problems with scaling on iPad. I need a quick and nice solution to scale my images in the correct ratio.

Currently my images mostly are too wide on iPad. I also only use 1x scale factor for my images (sometimes it's enough to set the `contentMode` of `imageViews` to `scaleAspectFill`).

How can I solve this issue, regarding the way I currently add images? Should I use `UIUserInterfaceIdiom` to detect if I have an iPad or iPhone to determine different positions and bounds?

```
func initbutton()
{
  let buttonX: CGFloat = 0.156
  let buttonY: CGFloat = 0.734
  let buttonWidth: CGFloat = 0.688
  let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 0.076

  button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(buttonX * view.frame.width,
                                             buttonY * view.frame.height,
                                             buttonWidth * view.frame.width,
                                             buttonHeight * view.frame.height))

  button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "button.png")!)
  view.addSubview(button)
}
```

Comment: You should read the Human Interface Guidelines, you should be creating 1,2,3x depending on the devices you want to support,iOS do the scaling for you so you don't need to worry about it, if you want to know which scale factor works for every devices, read this (top row texts): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Comment: @NiravDoctorwala *please*, on behalf of reviewers and readers everywhere, stop using `code formatting` (backticks) for things that aren't code. Why on earth would "scaling on iPad" or "right ratio" be formatted as code?